# Another word for 'symptoms' but not materalisation, illness, disease,

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word to fill in the blank.

> **Symptoms are inauspicious ______ that might be caused by the induced sensations. But they can also be a sign of a latent or a manifest disease.**

Would **occurrences** or **events** be considered appropriate?

The following words are not to be used:

- manifestation
- indication
- indicator
- sign
- mark
- feature
- trait;

Comment: Nothing here makes sense. What is an *induced sensation* that could *cause* a symptom?

Comment: That would take too long to describe. Let's imagine that a certain practice or agent induces certain sensations in the body, for example meditation or drugs. These induced sensations are different from the symptoms one might experience.

Comment: Well, given that the sentence itself doesn't make any sense to me, I'm unable to comment on what particular additional word should be added to it. And I don't follow your comment either. Surely, induced or not, sensations are still things that are experienced. Otherwise they wouldn't be called *sensations*. Nor do I see how a *sensation* (of any kind) could cause something. Sensations are *themselves* symptoms . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford - great comment but I would not in every case equate sensations with symptoms. E.g. people who take a brew called 'ayahuasca' report certain sensations, e.g. something unfathomable crawling through their body. But they also experience nausea or cramps, which could be classified as symptoms.

Comment: @johann_ka  You should probably listen to what Jason Bassford is saying.  It may be that there is a clinical difference between a "sensation" and a "symptom", but in this context the difference is not obvious to a native English speaker.  Are you writing to an audience already familiar with this distinction?  Or to the general public?  As with any language, it's important to consider how words communicate meaning, and not just shove any old word in there that seems to fit.

Comment: @johann_ka  For example, your use of "inauspicious" is confusing when paired with "symptoms".  What do you think "inauspicious" *should* mean?  Because I think you may be mixing it up with a different word like **"innocuous"**

Comment: I agree with the other comments, the other words used in the passage are quite fuzzy. You should provide the context - where this text comes from and what it is about. I would guess that it is about some alternative medicine practice where the words "symptom", "sensation" and others may have meanings somewhat different than usual. I tried to answer the question without context, but it is just guess.

Comment: @Andrew 'inauspicious' as in 'unfavourable', 'inauspicious symptoms' are undesired events in the body; yes, the audience has already been introduced to the idea of distinguishing between sensations and symptoms.

Comment: @johann_ka  "Auspicious" has a similar root to ["augury"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/augur), from the Latin *auspex/augur* meaning **"the practice of foretelling future events"** (by observing the flight of birds).  "Inauspicious" means "unfavorable", but generally in the same kind of context as "ominous", referring to **omens** -- signs portending negative future events.  Your sentence is not about symptoms which **tell the future**, so "inauspicious" is not the right word.  Again, be careful when picking words from the dictionary without considering context and etymology.

Comment: @johann_ka  So the problem with this question is, if the sentence is already confusing, there is no word we can insert into the blank that will make sense.  You need a complete rewrite, and we try to avoid answering questions that are mostly *proofreading*.  However, if you rephrase your question using the advice in these comments, I would be happy to help you out.

Comment: Symptoms are significant **clues** that might be caused by the induced sensations. But I don't much like the word inauspicious here. Symptoms are not events or occurrences.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as a gaming question. It is not possible to answer when arbitary rules about which words are "not permitted" are set.

Answer (score 2):

I think "features" is best; "traits" could also work. I would avoid the rest, because they are rarely used without further qualifications. (E.g. if you used "manifestations", I would automatically think "manifestations of what?")

Answer (score 0):

A word that can be used to fill in the blank is "responses".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to say

- Symptoms = X
- X can be caused by induced sensations
- OR X can be be sign of disease.

X isn't needed unless your reader/listener doesn't know the definition of *symptom*.
*Symptom* is  a basic enough word that If the reader doesn't know what it is he/she can consult a dictionary.

> Symptoms are inauspicious ______ that might be caused by the induced sensations. But they can also be a sign of a latent or a manifest disease.
>
> Symptoms might be caused by the induced sensations. But they can also be a sign of a latent or a manifest disease.

You can also provide examples this way if what you're really trying to do is narrow down the number of symptoms the reader/writer should be thinking about:

> Symptoms such as X, Y, Z might be caused by the induced sensations. But they can also be a sign of a latent or a manifest disease.